# d3.event.shiftKey causing crash with Force-Directed Layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm attempting to create a Shift+Click action **in a force-directed layout** with the following code applied to node shapes:

```
.on("click",function(){
        if(d3.event.shiftKey){
                //do something
        }
});
```

The code tends to function correctly, but will occasionally crash the browser (both Chrome and Safari crash). It seems that the **crash occurs after the following sequence**:

- Click and drag cursor anywhere outside of node (so that the text cursor is revealed)
- Hold down shift while holding down cursor outside of node (still shows text cursor)
- Click node

**update: It appears that this crash is not exclusive to my code. I can crash my browsers on any force-directed layout by doing the following: while keeping shift held down the whole time, click empty space, click node.**

Perhaps some built-in shift functionality is getting in the way of D3's? The alt key works fine with my above code, for instance.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or a bl.ocks?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Have you checked the respective bug trackers?

Comment: From this existing fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/zuzzy/dFd3H/2/), I found that the problem is not exclusive to my Shift+Click event - it appears to happen with all force-directed layouts. Hold shift during the following: click empty space, click a node - browser crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have run into a similar situation and it appears to be a Chrome bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114745

Its possible that the default behavior in webkit where shift-click selects all text up to current cursor position is the mechanism for the crash.

We have not spent the time to track the specifics yet in d3 but as the bug report suggests it may be possible to get around it for now with a "blur" call on any formerly focused elements (see the bug report).